# Neural network - solve a net with time arrays and different sample rate

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have 3 measurements for a machine. Each measurement is trigged every time its value changes by a certain delta.

I have these 3 data sets, represented as Matlab objects: `T1`, `T2` and `O`. Each of them has a `obj.t` containing the timestamp values and `obj.y` containing the measurement values.

I will measure `T1` and `T2` for a long time, but `O` only for a short period. The task is to reconstruct `O_future` from  `T1` and `T2`, using the existing values for `O` for training and validation.

Note that `T1.t`, `T2.t` and `O.t` are not equal, not even their frequency (I might call it 'variable sample rate', but not sure if this name applies).

Is it possible to solve this problem using Matlab or other software? Do I need to resample all data to a common time vector?

Comment: I'm working on a heuristic algorithm to solve the same problem, which I think can be used to train the neural network.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the common time. Below some basic code which does this. (I  guess you might know how to do it but just in case). However, the second option might bring you further...

```
% creating test signals
t1 = 1:2:100;
t2 = 1:3:200;
to = [5 6 100  140];
s1 = round (unifrnd(0,1,size(t1)));
s2 = round (unifrnd(0,1,size(t2)));
o  = ones(size(to));


maxt = max([t1 t2 to]);
mint = min([t1 t2 to]);
% determining minimum frequency
frequ = min([t1(2:length(t1)) - t1(1:length(t1)-1) t2(2:length(t2)) - t2(1:length(t2)-1) to(2:length(to)) - to(1:length(to)-1)] );

% create a time vector with highest resolution 
tinterp = linspace(mint,maxt,(maxt-mint)/frequ+1);

s1_interp = zeros(size(tinterp));
s2_interp = zeros(size(tinterp));
o_interp  = zeros(size(tinterp));
for i = 1: length(t1)
    s1_interp(ceil(t1(i))==floor(tinterp)) =s1(i);
end
for i = 1: length(t2)
    s2_interp(ceil(t2(i))==floor(tinterp)) =s2(i);
end
for i = 1: length(to)
    o_interp(ceil(to(i))==floor(tinterp)) = o(i);
end
figure,
subplot 311
hold on, plot(t1,s1,'ro'),  plot(tinterp,s1_interp,'k-')
legend('observation','interpolation')
title ('signal 1')

subplot 312
hold on, plot(t2,s2,'ro'),  plot(tinterp,s2_interp,'k-')
legend('observation','interpolation')
title ('signal 2')

subplot 313
hold on, plot(to,o,'ro'),  plot(tinterp,o_interp,'k-')
legend('observation','interpolation')
title ('O')
```

Its not ideal as for large vectors this might become ineffective as soon as you have small sampling frequencies in one of the signals which will determine the lowest resolution.

Another option would be to define a coarser time vector and look at the number of events that happend in a certain period which might have some predictive power as well (not sure about your setup). 
The structure would be something like

```
coarse_t = 1:5:100;
s1_coarse = zeros(size(coarse_t));
s2_coarse = zeros(size(coarse_t));
o_coarse  = zeros(size(coarse_t));
for i = 2:length(coarse_t)
    s1_coarse(i) = sum(nonzeros(s1(t1<coarse_t(i) &  t1>coarse_t(i-1))));
    s2_coarse(i) = sum(nonzeros(s2(t2<coarse_t(i) &  t2>coarse_t(i-1))));
    o_coarse(i)  = sum(nonzeros(o(to<coarse_t(i) &  to>coarse_t(i-1))));
end
```

Comment: Thank you horseshoe. I'm indeed trying to solve the time problem by interpolating. Your code gives me some ideas, I will try them out. To other readers: is it really imposible to solve the problem without resampling?